Laptop refusing to wakeup after closed on Pop_OS
brand new Linux user here. I've just installed Pop_OS on my laptop (Acer Predator Triton 500 SE) yesterday, and am having some trouble when my computer goes to sleep. When I open my laptop back up after having closed it it only shows a black screen and is unresponsive to pressing keys, wiggling and clicking the mouse, or briefly pressing the power button; I end up having to shut it off completely and reboot it. I've let it idle to see if it has the same problem waking up when it sleeps after inactivity and it doesn't (or, at least, that aspect of the issue has already been fixed by something I've done).
Things I've already tried that haven't worked for me:
Running the command sudo kernelstub -a mem_sleep_default=deep
Shutting off the System76 Power extension
Suspending various parts of hardware on wakeup as per this guy: https://www.vegard.net/how-to-suspend-pop-os/; while he had the opposite problem as me, I tried his method of shutting off specific parts to see if they were impacting anything, but alas it didn't work for me.
Here are logs for my last boot, if that's useful; if it doesn't have anything needed for problemsolving I could always try to get another
Jul 08 12:52:30 pop-os kernel: Linux version 6.9.3-76060903-generic (jenkins@warp.pop-os.org) (x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-12 (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 12.3.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) > 
Jul 08 12:52:30 pop-os kernel: Command line: initrd=\EFI\Pop_OS-84099964-cc78-4e2e-b771-4f1ec55a6506\initrd.img root=UUID=84099964-cc78-4e2e-b771-4f1ec55a6506 ro quiet loglevel=0 systemd.show> 
Jul 08 12:52:30 pop-os kernel: KERNEL supported cpus: 
Jul 08 12:52:30 pop-os kernel:   Intel GenuineIntel 
Jul 08 12:52:30 pop-os kernel:   AMD AuthenticAMD 
Jul 08 12:52:30 pop-os kernel:   Hygon HygonGenuine 
Jul 08 12:52:30 pop-os kernel:   Centaur CentaurHauls 
Jul 08 12:52:30 pop-os kernel:   zhaoxin   Shanghai   
Jul 08 12:52:30 pop-os kernel: x86/split lock detection: #AC: crashing the kernel on kernel split_locks and warning on user-space split_locks 
Jul 08 12:52:30 pop-os kernel: BIOS-provided physical RAM map: 
Jul 08 12:52:30 pop-os kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000000009efff] usable 
Jul 08 12:52:30 pop-os kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000009f000-0x00000000000fffff] reserved 
Jul 08 12:52:30 pop-os kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x0000000038f98fff] usable 
Jul 08 12:52:30 pop-os kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000038f99000-0x0000000039898fff] reserved 
Jul 08 12:52:30 pop-os kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000039899000-0x00000000424aefff] usable 
Jul 08 12:52:30 pop-os kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000424af000-0x00000000442fefff] reserved 
Jul 08 12:52:30 pop-os kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000442ff000-0x0000000044b2efff] ACPI NVS 
Jul 08 12:52:30 pop-os kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000044b2f000-0x0000000044bfefff] ACPI data 
Jul 08 12:52:30 pop-os kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000044bff000-0x0000000044bfffff] usable 
Jul 08 12:52:30 pop-os kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000044c00000-0x0000000048ffffff] reserved 
Jul 08 12:52:30 pop-os kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000049e00000-0x000000004f7fffff] reserved 
Jul 08 12:52:30 pop-os kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000c0000000-0x00000000cfffffff] reserved 
Jul 08 12:52:30 pop-os kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fe010000-0x00000000fe010fff] reserved 
Jul 08 12:52:30 pop-os kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fed20000-0x00000000fed7ffff] reserved 
Jul 08 12:52:30 pop-os kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000ff000000-0x00000000ffffffff] reserved 
Jul 08 12:52:30 pop-os kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000100000000-0x00000004b07fffff] usable 
Jul 08 12:52:30 pop-os kernel: NX (Execute Disable) protection: active 
Jul 08 12:52:30 pop-os kernel: APIC: Static calls initialized 
Jul 08 12:52:30 pop-os kernel: e820: update [mem 0x35618018-0x3563e857] usable ==> usable 
Jul 08 12:52:30 pop-os kernel: extended physical RAM map: 
Jul 08 12:52:30 pop-os kernel: reserve setup_data: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000000009efff] usable 
Jul 08 12:52:30 pop-os kernel: reserve setup_data: [mem 0x000000000009f000-0x00000000000fffff] reserved 
Jul 08 12:52:30 pop-os kernel: reserve setup_data: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x0000000035618017] usable 
Jul 08 12:52:30 pop-os kernel: reserve setup_data: [mem 0x0000000035618018-0x000000003563e857] usable 
Jul 08 12:52:30 pop-os kernel: reserve setup_data: [mem 0x000000003563e858-0x0000000038f98fff] usable 
Jul 08 12:52:30 pop-os kernel: reserve setup_data: [mem 0x0000000038f99000-0x0000000039898fff] reserved 
Jul 08 12:52:30 pop-os kernel: reserve setup_data: [mem 0x0000000039899000-0x00000000424aefff] usable 
Jul 08 12:52:30 pop-os kernel: reserve setup_data: [mem 0x00000000424af000-0x00000000442fefff] reserved 
Jul 08 12:52:30 pop-os kernel: reserve setup_data: [mem 0x00000000442ff000-0x0000000044b2efff] ACPI NVS 
Jul 08 12:52:30 pop-os kernel: reserve setup_data: [mem 0x0000000044b2f000-0x0000000044bfefff] ACPI data 
Jul 08 12:52:30 pop-os kernel: reserve setup_data: [mem 0x0000000044bff000-0x0000000044bfffff] usable 
Jul 08 12:52:30 pop-os kernel: reserve setup_data: [mem 0x0000000044c00000-0x0000000048ffffff] reserved 
Jul 08 12:52:30 pop-os kernel: reserve setup_data: [mem 0x0000000049e00000-0x000000004f7fffff] reserved 
Jul 08 12:52:30 pop-os kernel: reserve setup_data: [mem 0x00000000c0000000-0x00000000cfffffff] reserved 
Jul 08 12:52:30 pop-os kernel: reserve setup_data: [mem 0x00000000fe010000-0x00000000fe010fff] reserved 
Jul 08 12:52:30 pop-os kernel: reserve setup_data: [mem 0x00000000fed20000-0x00000000fed7ffff] reserved 
Jul 08 12:52:30 pop-os kernel: reserve setup_data: [mem 0x00000000ff000000-0x00000000ffffffff] reserved 
Jul 08 12:52:30 pop-os kernel: reserve setup_data: [mem 0x0000000100000000-0x00000004b07fffff] usable 
Jul 08 12:52:30 pop-os kernel: efi: EFI v2.7 by INSYDE Corp. 
Jul 08 12:52:30 pop-os kernel: efi: ACPI=0x44bfe000 ACPI 2.0=0x44bfe014 TPMFinalLog=0x44a85000 SMBIOS=0x4295f000 SMBIOS 3.0=0x4295d000 MEMATTR=0x398a8018 ESRT=0x398ab898 INITRD=0x3582fc98 RNG> 
Jul 08 12:52:30 pop-os kernel: random: crng init done 
Jul 08 12:52:30 pop-os kernel: efi: Remove mem73: MMIO range=[0xc0000000-0xcfffffff] (256MB) from e820 map 
Jul 08 12:52:30 pop-os kernel: e820: remove [mem 0xc0000000-0xcfffffff] reserved lines 1-53

I could always just disable suspend, but that'd be annoying and I'd rather not have to do that unless I really need to. It might be a problem with my laptop's nvidia driver, but who knows? In any case, thanks in advance for the help!

Update UEFI before any further troubleshooting.

For suspend-to-ram (deep), the kernel does a little bit of housekeeping then hands control over to the BIOS (ACPI). While it is possible that the handover is failing in some way, I would expect that to be visible in the log extract you showed us. If the handover is successful and the machine fails to wake when expected, then the answer lies in the BIOS, not the OS.
